# make cols fit neetly horizontally when they cant fit in 1 row

Tags: html, css, css-grid, bootstrap-5

I have a row with 6 cols, when the cols cant fit next to eah other on the screen 2 of them get put below, but it looks a bit messy.

I could fix this with a media query but i was wondering if theres a better way to make the 2 that get put below get placed more "nicely"

this image might be better than my explanation

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK4Jh.png)

update (example code)

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 quick_skills_col" id="box">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'python_logo.png' %}" alt="python_logo">
                    <p>
                      python
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'AWS-logo-2.jpg' %}" alt="aws_logo">
                    <p>
                      aws
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'selenium.png' %}" alt="selenium_logo">
                    <p>
                      selenium
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'Csharp_Logo.png' %}" alt="csharp_logo">
                    <p>
                      C#
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'django.png' %}" alt="django_logo">
                    <p>
                      django
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'docker.png' %}" alt="docker_logo">
                    <p>
                      docker
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: We have nothing to work with here. Please provide some sample code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi, ive added the html in question

Comment: Note: ID's should be unique. Having multiple element with `id="box"` is invalid html.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easiest with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). In this demo I have put the content in a resizable container so you can see how the items reflow.

```css
#resizeAreaForDemo {
  border: 2px dotted;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 4px;
}

.row .quick_skills_col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  /* the min size you want these to be */
  height: 80px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.row .quick_skills_col img {font-size:8px;}
```

```html
<div id="resizeAreaForDemo">

<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 quick_skills_col" id="box0">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'python_logo.png' %}" alt="python_logo">
                    <p>
                      python
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box1">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'AWS-logo-2.jpg' %}" alt="aws_logo">
                    <p>
                      aws
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box2">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'selenium.png' %}" alt="selenium_logo">
                    <p>
                      selenium
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box3">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'Csharp_Logo.png' %}" alt="csharp_logo">
                    <p>
                      C#
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box4">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'django.png' %}" alt="django_logo">
                    <p>
                      django
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2  quick_skills_col" id="box5">
                  <div class = "quick_skill">
                    <img class="quick_skill_img" src="{% static 'docker.png' %}" alt="docker_logo">
                    <p>
                      docker
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```